# How to use jQuery Multiselect plugins in Backbone.js Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-ui-multiselect

What is the magic trick to get multiselect jQuery plugin to work in Backbone.js Application? I have tried to use SumoSelect, Bootstrap-Multiselect, Chosen and jQuery UI's MultiSelect.

I have a Model and it's Collection. I'm setting e.g. SumoSelect plugin in View's render method with code below

```
render : function() {   
....

    // Time for DOM
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".dropdown-features", this.$el).SumoSelect()
    }, 100);

    return this;                            
},
```

Class dropdown-features is defined in template file like this

```
<div class="filter-header">
    <strong>${title}</strong>       
</div>              
        <div>
            <select class="dropdown-features">                   
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
            </select>
        </div>          
</div>
```

Model and Collection are defined normally like in Backbone.js Applications.

```
MyApp.Models = MyApp.Models || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    MyApp.Models.Facet = Backbone.Model.extend({

        idAttribute: "name"
    });

})();
```

and

MyApp.Collections = MyApp.Collections || {};

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    MyApp.Collections.Facets = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: MyApp.Models.Facet,

        initialize : function(models, options) {
            if (_.isUndefined(options) ||
                _.isUndefined(options.label) ||
                _.isUndefined(options.title)) {
                throw new Error('Label and title must be given Facets collection in initialization.');
            } else {
                this.label = options.label;
                this.title = options.title;
            }
        },

        getName: function() {
            return this.title;
        },

        getLabel: function() {
            return this.label;
        },

        getFirstLabel: function() {
            return this.first().get('name');
        }
    });    
})();
```

If I use pure HTML Select-tag everything works fine, but when trying to use Plugins mentioned above I can't get any data into Select Options. Select widget changes to new style but doesn't contain anything except "Choose...".

I'm quite new Backbone.js user I haven't use UI Plugings before in Backbone.js Applications.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: This should be fairly straight forward, why dont you post the rest of your view code, and a jsfiddle example of what youre doing so we can debug it.

Comment: Hello, that View contains only calls to other template-parts thats why I didn't copy them. But problem is that why html select works, plugin not?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, took me a bit, but i got it. Seems like all these frameworks are taking the easy way out (im not blaming them, i would have done the same thing) and essentially doing: `$(<element you give it>).parent()` issue, when you're inside a backbone view, for the most part, the `el` hasnt been attached to the DOM. Solutions:

- you can either use a `setTimeout` (not my cup of tee, its ugly and difficult to debug later on)
- you can create a wrapper (just add a `<div>` around your `<select>`)
- you can just attach it to where it needs to go THEN call `SumoSelect()` or equivalent

Example 1:

Im not going to show you how to do the `setTimeout` because i think you got it mastered.

Example 2:

```
var WrapperView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div', // <<< ----------------- look here
  template: _.template('<option value="<%=value%>"><%=name%></option>'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var view = this;
    var select = $('<select>');
    view.$el.append(select);
    myCollection.each(function(model){
      select.append(view.template(model.toJSON()));
    });
    select.SumoSelect(); // <<< ----------------- look here
    return this.el;
  }
});

$('body').append((new WrapperView()).el);
```

Example 3:

```
var WaitView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'select', // <<< ----------------- look here
  template: _.template('<option value="<%=value%>"><%=name%></option>'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var view = this;
    myCollection.each(function(model){
      view.$el.append(view.template(model.toJSON()));
    });
    return this.el;
  }
});

var waitview = new WaitView();
$('body').append(waitview.el);
waitview.$el.SumoSelect(); // <<< ----------------- look here
```

Personally, i like option 2 the best, its the most compact option, option 1 i HATE with a passion, option 3 i can guarantee that you will forget about it, come back in 3 months and be confused as hell; but ultimately, its your decision. Here are examples 2 and 3 in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ghcp2g2t/4/

---

PS.Next time you ask a JS question PLEASE, pretty pretty please, add a jsfiddle or any kind of ready to go testing environment of the problem, it takes a lot of time to trace down the CDN urls and setup the test.

Comment: Hello Javier, this works nicely! I still wonder that because I should call this View from another View and not declare variable like: var waitview = new WaitView() what could be the proper way to do it in Backbone.js?

Comment: @user2707924 I need to know a tiny but more about your situation, but as a generic answer i would say: have `masterView`.`render()` set up the `subView`(s). If you want to ask another question make a new stackoverflow question since this would be out of the scope of this question and i'll be more than happy to answer it; 400 characters doesnt give me enough space to properly give an example, not to mention that the spacing would make it unreadable.

Comment: @user2707924 if that solved the main issue, mind upvoting and accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a scope issue...

```
// Time for DOM
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".dropdown-features", this.$el).SumoSelect()
}, 100);
```

this.$el is probably undefined.  Does this work?

```
var _this = this;

// Time for DOM
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".dropdown-features", _this.$el).SumoSelect()
}, 100);
```

Or my personal preference of:

```
var _this = this;

// Time for DOM
setTimeout(function(){
  _this.$el.find('.dropdown-features').SumoSelect()
}, 100);
```